# Where (or how) should we host PDFs?

Tags: discussion

In this (very good) answer, the answerer linked to a PDF that is on a dropbox site:

[Overhauling Shimano Dynamo Hubs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/36529/11160)

There's no problem with the answer itself, but in comments/discussion, we noted that it'd be best if it were hosted on a more stable site (perhaps like the images on SE are hosted on imgur).

Thoughts?

Comment: The issue there is that the linking user doesn't want to mirror the content, but we really have to for stability. The issue is that pdf is a final output format, so converting it to something more usable is generally difficult. Screenshots would work here, but they're a poor solution. Annoyingly, this is an archive of a broken web page, but at least the text inside is copyable. Ideally someone would re-create the web page in that answer.

Comment: Ideally someone would re-create the web page in that answer (which isn't hard, but the user might revert it since they explicitly want not to do that).

Comment: Copyright comes into it too - trinity bicycles seems to be gone, or at least their web site has left the internet.

The content sans pictures is available here https://web.archive.org/web/20090107023114/http://trinitybicycles.com/shimanodynohuboverhaul.php  but the pictures are pretty important.

I'm tempted to edit the answer and copy/paste the entire relevant content of the PDF, so that its searchable.  And provide attribution to the original sources of course.

This is a specific answer about that PDF.   Would a Shimano tech ref page be any different?  I think not.

Comment: I've got halfway through but can't do the images yet - will finish it off in 6 hours.

Comment: Completed - That's a lot of work.   If the PDFs were hosted like images, would the search engine find text in them?

Comment: PDF is not specific to bicycle.  Meta.stackexchange.com is a more appropriated site for this question.  Not single SE supports posting of PDF.   There would be a myriad of problems.  Yes pretty much everyone has a PDF viewing application installed but it is not guaranteed.   You cannot even use HTML in any SE site.   Some sites support Latex or Math Jax but that is a much simpler and stable.

Answer (score 2):

I guess my actions on this would speak as an answer?

**Answer** If the content is worth saving, then copy/paste the relevant text and then insert the images inline.  Full accreditation of the source should be given as well as a link to where the PDF came from, regardless of whether the PDF link is stale or working.

**Method Details**  I copied and pasted the text into the answer, and then edited it to remove the repeating header/footer.

To get the images I opened the PDF in GIMP and imported (rasterised) to a resolution of 150 DPI.  Then I manually selected each relevant image, cut it out and pasted it into a new file.  An Autocrop removed extra whitespace, and then the image was saved as a PNG.

One image was blurry, a "sharpen" helped a little.  Another image had jpegged text in the image, so I cleared that and retyped it.  At least once, two images were taken together because they were side by side.

Once that was done I inserted each images in the correct place in the text.  I was careful to keep all the pictures and text in the same relative position and the only thing to change would be text wrapping at the end of each line.